# How to tell whether a re-install failed

Tags: macos, install, software-update, recovery

I tried to do a re-install, and got a message that it could not be done.  I tried again, and when I came back before the predicted two-plus hours were complete, it was at log in screen.  So I don't know whether an error display timed out and rebooted the old system or whether the re-install succeeded and booted the newly installed system.

Since the first attempt failed ("storage system verify or repair failed"), I would like some way to determine what happened with the second.  There's probably an indication somewhere in some log file.

I have a cron job that tells me when version numbers change, but these are both the same (latest) version.

Update: I still don't know the answer, but after a lot of kernel panics, I persuaded Apple to repair the laptop.  They replaced the main logic board and the touch sensor, and sent it back worse than before.

Comment: Closing due to "lack of detail" doesn't make sense when the question is how to get that detail.

Comment: There is an answer below with pointers on what you can do. Did you try this, what was the result? Also, the question as such lacks context: what kind of reinstall, is the reinstall supposed to solve a problem (and if yes, which one?). Basically all we have is some vague description of what you did, without even a clear question in the post.

Comment: That suggests a (possibly) better way to do an install.  It does not tell how to find the reason an already tried install failed.  And the question in larger font at the top (title) seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Well, if a reinstall fails, I would expect an error message and/or the system probably doesn't work. As I said: we lack a lot of context here.

Comment: "got a message that it could not be done"  If the message had more detail than that, I would not have posted the question.

Comment: So we already have two questions: "how to tell if a re-install failed" and "how to tell if a re-install failed without telling me in enough detail"?

Comment: What Mac model, and what version of MacOS, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Before you dig into the install logs (which may have thousands of entries) have you exhausted the normal steps in order?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212526

If you’re committed to going to the mat on an update of macOS, I recommend either [LockRattler or SilentKnight](https://eclecticlight.co/lockrattler-systhist/) instead of the console app.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2022/06/14/what-to-do-when-an-update-wont-install-correctly/

Apple also provides information on the logging as a registered developer - filter on macOS and then search for the link called Install.

- https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?platform=macos

In most cases looking over all versions of `/var/log/system.log` and `/var/log/install.log` (sometimes the compressed previous "rolled" version of those log files have the items you need and not the current file) should have the key details on all installs successful or failed.

Comment: They may be better methods of installing, but they don't answer the question on how to find out why a past attempt failed.

Comment: I've documented where apple discloses this for you @WGroleau - you'll need to be a registered (which usually means paid) developer to get access to that document. Have you opened a free support case with Apple to see if they will disclose to you the location of the install log for your chosen macOS upgrade / install?

Comment: Wow, if those logs are the _easiest_ way, bummer.  I posted the Q hoping for something easier.  I did make several bug reports that Apple is ignoring, and numerous crash reports.  Also wasted at least a hundred hours on the phone with AppleCare before they offered to "repair" the laptop.  They replaced the logic board and the touch sensor (or so they claim) and sent it back worse than before.